# how to get historic head count for company based on start and end dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

HR gave me a very basic `.xlsx` file:

```
name   startdate   enddate
jdoe   4/30/2005  
kdoe   11/1/2005   3/11/05
```

Not everyone has a end date.

What they want is a list of per week or per day (not sure yet) historically what the head count of the company was/is

I've tried a pivot table and it will give me how many people joined or left during a month or year but not a cumulative total also I don't know how to add one and subtract the other.

Any ideas on a formula would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put dates in a column and next to it add the people that have joined and subtract the people who have left

> =countif(B$2:B$500,"<="&D2)-countif(C$2:C$500,"<="&D2)

where d2 is the column with your date you want head count at and cells B2:B500 contain startdate, C2:C500 contain enddate.